# How to make Ubuntu decrypt the specific directory?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, encryption, decryption

From the `nautilus` context menu, I have right clicked on `/home/myaccount/www/somefolder`, then I have clicked on **Encrypt Folder**. Now I would like to decrypt the folder. How can I do this? "Decrypt" command is not in the context menu!

[image]

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

me@pc:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
Unity
```

Comment: Please explain how you encrypted your folder? Have you written a script and embedded into nautilus? Per default I have only compress a folder, but not encrypt.

Comment: Indeed I don't remember that I had done such script for nautilus. I just find an encryption option in the context menu of right click at any folder. @abu_bua

Comment: That is not standard.  what is the output of `ls ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`?  Please [edit] your question and add that information there, then ping me @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby The output of `ls ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` is nothing

Comment: @SaidbakR : If my answer is wrong, provide the screenshot of your context menu, please.

Comment: @Christianus I have added a screen shot

Comment: @SaidbakR: Can you, please, tell us what version of (1) Linux, and (2) desktop environment do you use?

Comment: @SaidbakR: If you cannot describe it, prompt of `lsb_release -a` (Linux version), and `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` (desktop environment currently in use) would be useful.

Comment: @Christianus Please checkout the update

Comment: @SaidbakR: I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS 'xenial' with Unity on VMware: there is no such an option like 'Encrypt folder'. BTW, why does your desktop environment seem to be different than Unity, looking more like Cinnamon, GNOME, KDE? I have a memory of seeing 'Encrypt folder' on a different flavor of Linux (Mint?) or different desktop environment (Cinnamon, maybe?), but you need to help me with the reproduction of the process to obtain help.

Comment: @SaidbakR: You can also see whether the 'Encrypt folder' script was added, invoking a `nautilus-actions-config-tool` command or in `Ubuntu Tweak > Admins > Scripts`. If none of the tools is installed, yet, I think the solution is wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

`Nautilus` is the file manager created for GNOME, not a disk/data encryption backend. The context menu of `nautilus` offers you a possibility to compress (and encrypt) folder *via* `Archive Manager` (formerly: `File Roller`) which is another graphical interface – the frontend for the archiving utilities such as `tar` and `zip`<sup>1</sup> (the latter with encrypting abilities).

After successful encryption of the folder, you can decrypt it by clicking on `Extract Here` in `nautilus'` context menu (*right-clique window*), and typing the password into the dialog box invoked by the `Archive Manager`.

Tip and hint – to be wise after the damage done without awareness – if I may: Never encrypt the important data without testing how the encryption/decryption works in the first place! You cannot cancel already finished encryption, only stop (cancel) the process (not applicable in this case), and order the software decrypt already encrypted portion of data.

<sup>1</sup> [`File Roller at sourceforge.net`](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/features.html)